# Is this an ok way to nerf console.log?

Tags: javascript

After browsing some of the different methods of nerfing console.log, I wanted something much shorter... I was using the html5 boilerplate but it's a little over kill for just console.log.

Do you see any problems that I might run into using this? It seems to work great in the latest Chrome/FF and IE 7 & FF 3.6.

```
 if (!window.console) {window.console = {}}
 if (!window.console.log) {window.console.log = function () {}}
```

Comment: Oh nerf, as in the soft foamy toys. For example if your brother hit you full swing with a nerf bat it doesn't hurt, where as a real bat would really hurt. I've heard the reference used to indicate you're making sure if someone does something with code, it won't be destructive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, it's fine. Or even shorter:

```
if (!window.console) window.console = { log: function() { } };
```

Comment: Nice!! I was just wondering, is it possible for a certain browser to have window.console defined but window.console.log is undefined?

Comment: Sure, it's possible, but unlikely :) (no current browsers do, but it's imaginable one could in the future). Maybe stick with yours just to be safe.

Comment: Oh ok cool, I wasn't sure what the current/past browsers did. I supposed the worst that could happen is you remove the console.log ability lol. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 2):

```
window.console = window.console || {log : function(){}}
```